# Problem with insertion in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming

I have written a code for insertion in Binary Search Tree and its traversal.

```
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
node* createNode(int value)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->data = value;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

node *start = NULL;

void insertNode(int val)
{
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = createNode(val);
        return;
    }

    node *temp = start;
    while ((temp->left != NULL) && (temp->right != NULL))
    {
        if (val < temp->data)
        {
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        else if (val > temp->data)
        {
            temp = temp->right;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Already exists in tree\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    if (val < temp->data)
    {
        temp->left = createNode(val);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->right = createNode(val);
        return;
    }


}

void inorder(node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d \n", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

It does not work fine on some test cases.

For example, if insert 15, 25 and then 35, and then traverse the tree, it only prints 15 and 25.

I am not able to find out the problem in the code. What is the issue with my insertion logic?

Comment: you while condition is incorrect.. debug it and look at your current tree structure and why the while body will be skipped where it shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through the behavior -

---

1. you insert the 15. `if (start == NULL)`

   - this check creates the start node. Now there is a start node with value 15 and left and right as `NULL`.

---

2. you insert 25. `(temp->left != NULL) && (temp->right != NULL)`

   - this turns out to be false.
   - `(val < temp->data)` this check creates a right node.

---

3. you insert 35. `(temp->left != NULL) && (temp->right != NULL)`

   - **still** turns out to be false.
   - `(val < temp->data)` this check creates a right node (replacing the current right node). **Which is not right.**

---

You need to correct the while loop condition here.